# Inverse function of y = x + (0.022 - x) ^ 1.414?

Tags: equation-solving, inverse

I'm a software engineer with math classes through differential equations about 15 years in my past, and I've gotten stuck trying to invert an equation.

The equation:
$y = x + (0.022 - x)^{1.414}$.

In Mathematica form:

```
sapcClamp[y] := y + ((22 / 100) - y) ^ (1414 / 100);  
Solve[sapcClamp[y] == x, y]
```

Note:

- `0 <= x < 0.022`
- Phyiscally relevant x/y values range from 0.0 to 1.0.

This hangs Mathematica indefinitely until the kernel is quit and restart, which indicates strongly there's no easy solution here.

Messing around on paper, with Reduce, FindRoot, Googling, Youtube, on paper has gotten me ~nowhere. Yet this doesn't feel complicated enough to me that there's simply *no* way to solve it.

Any tips?

Comment: Algebraically, the equation with the rational exponent `1414/1000` = `707/500` is in effect a degree-707 polynomial. That means it's simple enough for there to be a way to solve it (but not in terms of the usual elementary functions); but it has 707 (complex) solutions. The following returns 707: `Solve[(y-x)^500 == (11/500-x)^707, x]`. If `1.414` represents an approximate real number, then things are more complicated. (Do you know that solutions to polynomial equations of degree 5 and up cannot be expressed in terms of n-th roots, except in special cases? Your problem is not simple.)

Comment: From documentation of the `FoxH`-function: The roots of general trinomial equation $z^n-z-t=0$ are given by `roots = Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/(n - 1)]^-j + t/(n - 1)FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {0, n/(n - 1)}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {0, 1/(n - 1)}}}, t Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/(n - 1)]^j];` In your case $z=0.022-x$, $y= t- 0.022$ and $n=1.414$. So, you need `FoxH`

Comment: For the derivation of series solution of your equation see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation

Comment: @MichaelE2, what if 1.414 is not 707/500 but sqrt(2)?

Comment: @CarstenS This equation has one real solution, which I suppose DanielHuber and BobHanlon find numerically.

Comment: @CarstenS As I said, "things are more complicated." The point is that the OP's intuitive view did not grasp the complexity of the problem. So numerical solutions are probably better than symbolic ones here, esp. if one may restrict to reals. The first solution returned by `Solve[]` (based on the exponent 1414/1000 given in the OP) is probably real. It takes up about 1.1MB, and the first time I evaluated it at 32-digit precision, it ran out of precision (I think) after several minutes. I gave up, since it's a silly way to go anyway.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I agree, no reason to expect a closed form solution.

Comment: The point on problem complexity is well-taken, its tough because I do need to code a solution outside Mathematica...but I suppose a straightforward equivalent is binary search for the answer, which I previously would have thought as "hacky", but its really just efficient.

Comment: Can't you just use Newton's method to invert `sapcClamp[]`? You can use the line through the end points to give a good starting point, since your function is almost straight anyway.

Comment: @CarstenS Why no closed form? I gave a closed form solution above.

Comment: @yarchik I can't get the `FoxH` solution to work for me. I wouldn't be surprised if `n` has to be an integer.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of worrying about an analytical solution, it can be done numerically by an interpolating function:

```
y[x_] = x + (22/1000 - x)^(1414/1000);
dat = Table[Reverse@{x, y[x]}, {x, 0, 0.022, 0.022/100}];
ifun = Interpolation[dat];
Plot[ifun[x], {x, y[0], 0.022}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Note that `0.022` is `22/1000` and `1.414` is `1414/1000`

```
0.022 == 22/1000 && 1.414 == 1414/1000

(* True *)

sapcClamp[y_] := y + ((22/1000) - y)^(1414/1000);
```

The inverse function is

```
sapcClampInv[x_?NumericQ] := y /. FindRoot[sapcClamp[y] == x, {y, 0.01}]

y0 = sapcClampInv[0]

(* -0.00654968 *)
```

The plot for the inverse function using either ParametricPlot or `sapcClampInv`

```
Legended[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{sapcClamp[y], y}, {y, y0, 0.022}],
  Plot[sapcClampInv[x], {x, 0, 0.022},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][2], Dashed]],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[
   {ColorData[97][1], Directive[Dashed, ColorData[97][2]]},
   {"ParametricPlot", "sapcClampInv"}],
  {.75, .4}]]
```

[image]